# Webpage preview npmjs using Angular

Tags: angular

I'm trying to implement this package in my project `npm install webpage-preview`, but I don't know where can I put this code, the `webpagePreview` is `undefined`. Is this just for angularjs or I missed something?

```
webpagePreview.generatePreview('http://www.google.com/', 'google',
    APP_ROOT + '/public/previews', null, null, function(error, sizePaths) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    else {
        console.log(sizePaths);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to import it in whatever component you are trying to call it from.

Example:

```
declare var require: any;

const webpagePreview = require('webpage-preview');
```

Or

```
import * as webpagePreview from 'webpage-preview';
```